# Best way to detect if a function was called with the correct number of arguments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, error-handling, arguments, overloading, function-call

To my understanding function overloading is not really a thing in JS. Which is why this will **not** throw an error

```
function f(first, second){}

f(); // no error
f(1) // still no error
f(1,2) // no error and correct
```

I would like to check every function, if I called it with the correct number of arguments. A way to do this would be to add something like this to every function

```
if(function.length !== arguments.length){
/*error detected*/
}
```

The downside is, that I would have to add this to ever function.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You should use TypeScript.

Comment: how should this work?

Comment: Maybe just check your code with ESLint?

Comment: Unfortunately in this project we are using JS. Still thanks for the advice :)

Comment: you could check each argument on its own.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, ESLint would be an option. Still I am looking for an "actual" solution. Something that would sort of simulate overloading in other programming languages and that would throw an error.

Comment: Sorry, it's just not how Javascript works. Overloading is handled within the function, and it requires the ability to call the function with different number of arguments.

Comment: Look at jQuery, for example.

Comment: @Barmar Was afraid that would be the answer. What do you mean with JQuery? Is there a $.checkOverload() thing?

Comment: I mean jQuery is an example of a library that makes extensive use of calling functions with different numbers of arguments. `$("selector").click()` sends a click event, `$("selector").click(function() {...})` adds a click listener.

Comment: @Barmar Ok, I get what you mean.

Comment: actually i don't know, what you really want. a check of all function before calling?

Comment: @NinaScholz (compare with given example) In other languages like Java or C# f() or f(1) would throw an error. If the function f "relies" on having 2 arguments passed into it, my code will break, since I pass only zero or one argument into f. I would like my program to throw an error, whenever I pass the wrong number of args into a function.

Comment: i understand the probkem, but not the point (in time sense) where it should happen

Comment: I'd recommed to rather use multiple functions with simpler/clear interfaces than trying to push as much versatility as possible into a single function. Take a closer look at "overloaded functions" in other languages. If you're precise, then you don't have a single overloaded function there either, but instead you have a bunch of funtions that go by the same name/property name, each one with a single distinct interface. And the engine decides, due to the passed types, wich function to use; only in JS you cannot have that kind of ambiguity.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you very much for the advice. This is a thing I always try to follow. Here I am trying to catch errors I do by mistake, e.g. just forgetting to pass an argument. Barmar already suggested to use ESLint, which is ok, still I am looking for a nice solution to do this inside the actual code, not "just" the linter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a proxy, you still have to modify your code a little bit, but it gets the work done.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

```js
function getArgsProxy(fn) {

  var handler = {
    apply: function(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
      if (target.length != argumentsList.length) {
        throw new Error('Error message');
      }
      return target.apply(thisArg, argumentsList);
    }
  };

  return new Proxy(fn, handler);

}


/* USAGE */

var f = getArgsProxy(function(first, second) {});

f(); // error
f(1) // error
f(1, 2) // no error and correct

// or

function f(first, second) {}
var $f = getArgsProxy(f);

$f(); // error
$f(1); // error
$f(1, 2);
```

Comment: that is not really better as a direct check inside of the function.

Comment: it is, because you don't have to code the logic inside every function

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. Still I think @NinaScholz is right, since I still have to call the "check" in every function there is.

Comment: yeah, but you don't need to change your existing functions to add `if(function.length !== arguments.length) { }`, you create a proxy and that's all

Comment: @luisenrike You have a point. I could use this for every number of functions I want. This could be a nice solution ...

Comment: @luisenrike I have problems implementing your solution into my scripts. I think it is, because we now have the functions as variables and have to be careful that we define the variables, before we use them. Any advice for that?

Comment: yep, you need to define the variables before using them, you can use this approach, but you still need to define the proxy before using it: `var $f = getArgsProxy(f);

console.log($f(1,2));

function f(first, second) {
    return 5;
}`

Answer (score 0):

As luisenrike pointed out, a proxy is a nice way to solve this problem.

For all those new to proxies (like me), I would like to add, that you **still have to execute** the function, after calling the handler.

```
function getArgsProxy(fn) {

    var handler = {
        apply: function(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
            if (target.length != argumentsList.length) {
                console.warn('wrong number of arguments!');
                console.trace();
            } else {
                // execute the function fn
                // use return, in case your function has a return value
                return fn.apply(thisArg, argumentsList);
            }
        }
    };
    return new Proxy(fn, handler);
}
```